# Intellisense / code completion in VS Code not helpful with XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using **VS Code** (Version 1.12.2 on Ubuntu) to write C# and [XML Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features). Code completion gets in the way, no matter if I use the [C# XML Documentation Comments plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment) or not:

If I type a period (`.`) at the end of a sentence, I get suggestions. The first suggestion is `!--`. Why would I want to type that? Why would I even want suggestions when I just start a new sentence?

If I try to close an XML tag by writing `<` I get the same suggestion, so typing `</` will result in:

```
<summary>Test<!--/
/// [Cursor placed here][contents of the line that came next]
```

And if I try to add another tag after `<summary></summary>` I will automatically get a new pair of `<summary></summary>` tags.

You can see this in action here:

[image: Screencast of my typing gibberish.]

**How do I make this work reasonably, or at least turn off completion within XML comments?**

Comment: PS: I'd like to know if others are affected by this, or if it's just me / my machine. So if there's no workaround, I'd file a bug report on GitHub. Please tell me in the comments.

Comment: I have this problem too! :-( How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, the best way I know of to get around this is to disable "Accept Suggestion On Commit Character" in the VSCode settings. This way, the spacebar won't be treated as a request to autocomplete. I personally prefer to rely on "Accept Suggestion on Enter" anyway, so this works for me, but you might have different habits.